# Changing projection back and forward correction

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I Have an orthophoto which is set on a local CRS (EPSG:2039)

I also collect data with a WGS84 Application (Fulcrum)

In order to use the orthophoto in the app I had to reproject it from the local CRS to WGS84 (EPSG:4326).

Later on I exported the vector data (points) which is of course in WGS84 and again reprojected it back to the local CRS.

For some reason the new vector data does not match the map and has an offset of a few meters. I'm searching for a way to correct it and move the points so all of of them would fit the original orthophoto.

**In short what happened is**

I Took a raster and reprojected it from one CRS to another

I I used it to collect vector data and when I switched the vector data back to the original CRS, It was offset

In the photo you can see that the points that were supposed to be on the poles are in the middle of the road
[image]

Comment: What precision did your positioning have?

Comment: Was any geographic/datum transformation used for either/both conversions? If so, they need to be the same one.